# How to configure jekyll and specify allowed markdown syntax

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I am currently trying to combine markdown and mathjax for my static blog but it's been painful as kramdown is forcing me to use double dollar signs as delimiters for both block and inline math. And even after that I have to escape parentheses.

Is it possible to configure jekyll with a markdown parser that allows one to specify allowed markdown syntax? I would very much like to achieve what stackexchange did on the math site MSE.

Answer (score -1):

From [the Jekyll configuration page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/):

> If you’re interested in creating a custom markdown processor, you’re
>   in luck! Create a new class in the `Jekyll::Converters::Markdown`
>   namespace:
>
> ```
> class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::MyCustomProcessor
>   def initialize(config)
>     require 'funky_markdown'
>     @config = config
>   rescue LoadError
>     STDERR.puts 'You are missing a library required for Markdown. Please run:'
>     STDERR.puts '  $ [sudo] gem install funky_markdown'
>     raise FatalException.new("Missing dependency: funky_markdown")
>   end
>
>   def convert(content)
>     ::FunkyMarkdown.new(content).convert
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Once you’ve created your class and have it properly set up either as a
>   plugin in the `_plugins` folder or as a gem, specify it in your
>   `_config.yml`:
>
> ```
> markdown: MyCustomProcessor
> ```